# MySQL return nothing when three tables are joined. Two tables have foreign keys in third one. What is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, join

The following structure and query are very simple, but I do not understand why I do not get any results back:

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` 
JOIN post    ON comment.source_id = post.id 
JOIN article ON comment.source_id = article.id
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9143/2

I have tables "**article**", "**post**" and **comment** (in my real database this is something else, I am just making an example here). In "**comment**" table I have foreign key "**source_id**", connecting this comment table with both "**article**" and "**post**" table. This is because id's of articles and post will be unique, and will never clash.

I mean, if you look at my fiddle example, you will see that post id's are 2001 and 2002, while article id's are 3001 and 3002. And there will be never post with id of 3001 or article with id of 2001 (I know that you may think that this will happen, but it will not, because in real system, these ids are not auto incrementing).

As you can see, I would like to select data from all 3 tables, but I am getting nothing. Output should be something like:

```
id      source_id   text                id      title
 1      2001        First comment       2001    First post
 2      2002        Second comment      2002    Second Post
 3      3001        Third comment       3001    First article
 4      3002        Comment on article  3002    Second article
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Or this is not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database structure implies a relationship that goes from both `comment` to `post` and from `comment` to `article`. You need to treat these separately, and then merge the two:

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` 
JOIN post    ON comment.source_id = post.id 
UNION
SELECT * FROM `comment` 
JOIN article ON comment.source_id = article.id
```

This will work in your example, since the column formats for each half of the union are compatible. However, if your real use case has different columns, you might be best redesigning your database. There are two approaches you might take:

- Have a `type` column on a `written_work` table (or whatever you wish to call it) to determine if it is a post or an article. This only works if all (or at least most) of the columns can be used for all types.
- Or, if the format of various types will differ, it may be worth putting your common fields in `written_work` (what I would call a common or collective table), and then adding "specialising" tables if necessary. These contain fields that are only used in articles, or posts, and you have one per written work type. The relationship between `written_work` and the specialist table of the indicated type is 1:1.

If you can avoid "re-using" foreign keys, you will be able to use foreign key constraints, which will give you an extra level of confidence in the integrity of your data. It is not possible with your current design.

Comment: +1 for the 1:1 content type tables.  That would mean you could get rid of the existing awkward auto-increments on the articles and post tables.  When you find yourself doing stuff like that, it's usually a good sign that you should be taking a closer look at your schema.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I do not understand what you mean by: you might be best having a collective table for both posts and articles, and then adding 1:1 specialising tables if necessary.

Comment: Great @black. I've updated my post to explain more about the specialising tables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each comment belongs to either an article or a post, but not both.  By performing an inner join on both the page and article tables, you're looking for comments that are attached to both, and those don't exist.

These are classic one-to-many relationships, and there are a variety of ways you can redesign your schema to better handle them.  For example, for each distinct content type, you could add a `[content_type]_comment` table to map content to comments.

Answer (score 0):

These should be LEFT OUTER JOINs instead of INNER JOIN as you are connecting to the "post" OR the "article" table. INNER JOIN works when there is a post AND an article BOTH connecting to the comment.

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` 
LEFT JOIN post    ON comment.source_id = post.id 
LEFT JOIN article ON comment.source_id = article.id
;
```

Edit. It works in my local copy, but as SQL fiddle is buggy as hell, can't just display results with NULL rows, I can give you an example which displays there that this way of thinking was actually correct

```
SELECT 
comment.id as comment_id,  
source_id,
text,
IF(post.id IS NOT NULL, post.id, 0) as post_id,  
IF(post.title IS NOT NULL, post.title, 0) as post_title,
IF(article.id IS NOT NULL, article.id, 0) as article_id,  
IF(article.title IS NOT NULL, article.title, 0) as article_title
FROM `comment` 
LEFT JOIN post    ON comment.source_id = post.id 
LEFT JOIN article ON comment.source_id = article.id
;
```

Also I recommend aliasing the selects here for later processing. So the final query in your copy should be (and this one will not work in SQL fiddle because of the NULLs):

```
SELECT 
comment.id as comment_id,  
source_id,
text,
post.id as post_id,  
post.title as post_title,
article.id as article_id,  
article.title as article_title
FROM `comment` 
LEFT JOIN post    ON comment.source_id = post.id 
LEFT JOIN article ON comment.source_id = article.id
;
```

Comment: This still returns nothing. Have you tried this in fiddle ?

Comment: In the fiddle it doesn't work, but pasted the schema to my local copy and also pasted the very same query I gave you here as an answer and it worked. Exactly did what it should and what you expected. Please give it a try. You may also want to give an alias to post.id, artice.id, etc. in the select, because you will have problem later processing them.

Comment: This won't work because the two left joins will result in separate `id` and `title` columns; one for `post`, and one for `article`.  For a single set of columns halfer's approach of union does the trick.

Comment: I could alter the IF columns to merge the id and title columns (if one of them is null, use the other), but also, on the long way I think it is better, if we know we are actually collecting comments for an article or a post, we just know, that on the programming side we need to handle and take care of both.

Comment: "as SQL Fiddle is buggy" - I've not encountered any problems using it. If you have, would you report a bug? I think they are on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, will do. Anyway this one is easy to reproduce. Just click on the link, write SELECT 1, then write SELECT NULL (and compare it to your local machine's MySQL). It won't display anything where there are NULLs. I can actually thank a minus vote to this bug practically (that's why I edited the comment).